# Formatting topnav in CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, position

Can someone please help me figure out how to center my menu bar (w/ id = "topnav") at the top of my HTML page? I tried a bunch of things with background-size and nothing seems to be working. I want it to be fixed and fill the page horizontally when scrolling.

```
#topnav a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#topnav{
font-family: Courier;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
background: white;
/*background-size: 100% auto !important;*/
}
```

Comment: provide your HTML too

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the width to 100%?

EDIT:

```
#topnav{
font-family: Courier;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
background: black;
/*background-size: 100% auto !important;*/
width: 100%;
top: 0;
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to take margin-left instead of left

`#topnav {`
margin-left:-50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}

Comment: You need to take width also if its a div element